# Init members data with const reference

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a basic class `PElement<T>`. In order to implement my linked list, I want that object `PElement<T>` to have a pointer to the next `PElement<T>` and a pointer to the value, which is an instance of T.

This is what I wrote:

```
template<class T> 
    class PElement {
     public:
       //Données membre
       PElement * s;
       T * v;

       //Constructeur
       PElement(
       const PElement * suivant,
       const T *valeur
       ):s(suivant),v(valeur){}

};
```

And this is how I create my object in the `main.cpp` file:

```
//Test PElement<Double>
PElement<double> * l1;
double *a = new double(2);
double *b = new double(5);
double *c = new double(7.5);
double *d = new double(9);
l1 = new PElement<double>(new PElement<double>(new PElement<double>(new PElement<double>(NULL, d), c), b), a);

//Test PElement<String>
PElement<string> * l2;
string *e = new string("Carotte");
string *f = new string("Cerise");
string *g = new string("Orange");
l2 = new PElement<string>(new PElement<string>(new PElement<string>(NULL, g), f), e);
```

And finally this is the error I get:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const PElement<double> *' to 'PElement<double> *'

error C2439: 'PElement<double>::s' : member could not be initialized
```

(And the same two errors for the second parameter v (v for value))

What is wrong with my code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Holy overuse of `new` Batman!

Comment: What language did you use before? If we know, the easier it will explain the differences. Was it `Java`?

Comment: You can't safely assign a `const PElement*` to a `PElement *`.

Comment: Yeah I started learning with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor:

```
//Constructeur
PElement( const PElement * suivant, const T *valeur)
    :s(suivant)
    ,v(valeur)
{}
```

tries to initialize `s` that is `PElement*` with `suivant` that is
`const PElement*`.

It is not allowed by C++. It is wrong to do so because `const PElement*` means that pointed at object is immutable but `PElement*` means that pointed at object is mutable.

Your initialization tries to lose that immutability qualifier.
You can immediately fix it by accepting non-const values to your constructor:

```
//Constructeur
PElement( PElement* suivant, T* valeur)
    :s(suivant)
    ,v(valeur)
{}
```

However we mostly do not make our own linked lists in C++. Instead we use
`std::list<double>` or `std::list<std::string>` when we need linked list of doubles or strings.

Comment: And we are trying to create a generic implementation of graph in c++, so that's why we are creating everything with our own hand in class. In order to understand what we do.

Comment: @Indray C++ standard library does not contain generic graphs, but there are some free implementations in Boost.Graph library.